# C# Input Value how to validate from A to ZZZ

Tags: c#

Input Value can be from A to ZZZ (only alphabetical, no numeric characters) how can I validate a from and to field.

Where the input can be A or AA or AAA

- B   > A
- BB  > A
- BBB > A
- BBB < B
- BBB < BB
- DD  > C
  but then  D should be  < CC fails because it is not a lexicographical order

I was thinking check the length first because if the from length is less than to length then it will always be less. If equal in length then an alphabetical check.  Then I come unstuck.

Not simple lexicographical order because three possiable groups single, double, triple chars single group lower than double and triple group and double lower than triple group not just alphabetical.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't that simple lexicographical order?

Comment: Your definition of cases is not complete. For example: Is D > AA and > BB and > CCC? I ask because in that case a first step length check fails.

Comment: What do you need to validate, if from is less than to?

Comment: This ? `inputValue >= "A" && inputValue <= "ZZZ"`

Comment: Not simple lexicographical order because three possiable groups single, double, triple chars single group lower than double and triple group and double lower than triple group not just alphabetical.

Comment: Tim it batch number and the rules are as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following: Imagine the String AAA as a number, saying A*26^2 + A*26^1 + A*26^0

(Base 26, because there are that much letters)

Split the String, Cast values A to Z to 1 to 26 (WhiteSpace in front = 0) and you are done:

```
 A = 0*26^2 + 0*26^1 + 1*26^0 => 1
 B = 2 => 2
 ...
 Z = 26 => 26
 AA = 1 * 26^1 + 1 => 27
 ...
 ZZ = 26*26^1 + 26 = 702
 ...
 ZZZ = 26*26^2 + 26*26^1 + 26 => 18278
```

wrap it Like

```
    public int LetterCodeToInt(String LetterCode)
    {
        //fill up whitespaces in front.
        String s = LetterCode.PadLeft(3, '_').ToUpper();

        int value = 0;
        int k = s.Length -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] != '_')
            {
                //ASCII "A" is 65, subtract 64 to make it "1" 
                value += (((int)s[i]) - 64) * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(26, k));
            }
            k--;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

and you can do:

```
 if (LetterCodeToInt("AAA") > LetterCodeToInt("AZ")){

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about using a regexp? `\b[A-Z]{1,3}\b`

Comment: That will not allow him to compare two values, which is what I think he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
string from = "BB";
string to = "AAA";
bool valid = string.Compare(from, to) < 0; // false
```

So it works already in lexicographical order. [**Demo**](http://ideone.com/QFXTBA)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Create a custom comparer that checks the length first. For example:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.Length < y.Length) return -1;
        if (x.Length > y.Length) return 1;
        return Comparer.Default.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```